# CVS for Android Studio

Tags: android, cvs

So I'm guessing everyone have heard about or seen the new Android Studio. If not you can find it [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), it's wonderful!

The only thing I cannot figure out is how to install CVS on it? I know it's using the IntelliJ IDE but it's not exactly the same as the original. I have tried examples on how to install CVS for IntelliJ but they reference buttons and links in the IDE that does not exist for Android Studio. I installed GIT with ease, only struggling with CVS.

**EDIT**

I tried installing [this](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=idea_ce&pluginId=1471) plugin via `File/Settings/Plugins/Install Plugin From Disk` but after restart the IDE does not start up anymore and I have to manually delete the plugin from `...\.AndroidStudioPreview\config\plugins` for the IDE to start up again. The error says that the plugin is already installed but I cannot access it from the IDE. Anyone know of another plugin I can use?

Comment: mmmeeeeeeehhhhh.  Anyway those of us who already had it installed get nagged about every single day to upgrade so we already knew about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but if you get the plugin from JetBrains website and then load Android Studio and on the main page (when no project open) select configure > plugins and then install plugin from disk.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No need to install cvs plugin with android studio. Its already inbuilt with android studio IDE. Here is the path:
Find VCS on toolbar of android studio.
VCS->checkout from version control->CVS.
Then you have to configure your cvs path for the first time.